# i need my nav bar to shift my main page info

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am trying to create a navbar that shift all of the content on the screen to the right if you hover over the nav icon. i tried to do this by setting the navbar to the left by -250 px and having it to where if you hover over the nav icon it will transition to right by the same amount of pixels. i also tried to have the body shift over the same amount of pixels to the right but nothing is moving over besides the navbar. any suggestions and would really help out a lot thank you in advance.
html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="main_page.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Cal's Blog</title>
</head>
<body>
        <nav>
            <div class="sideNav" id="sideNav">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="bar1"></div>
                    <div class="bar2"></div>
                    <div class="bar3"></div>
                    <div class="navMenu">
                        <a href="#">about</a>
                        <a href="#">services</a>
                        <a href="#">clients</a>
                        <a href="#">contacts</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <h1> Cal's Blog</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

css code:

```
.container {
display: inline-block;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
width: 35px;
height: 5px;
background-color: #333;
margin: 6px 0;
transition: 0.4s;
position: relative;
}

.container:hover .bar1 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);

}

.container:hover .bar2 {
opacity: 0;
}

.container:hover .bar3 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
.navMenu {
height: 100%;
width: 250px; 
position: absolute; 
z-index: 1; 
top: 0; 
left: -250px;
background-color: #111; 
overflow-x: hidden; 
padding-top: 60px; 
transition: 0.5s;
}
.navMenu a{
padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 25px;
color: #818181;
display: block;
transition: 0.3s;
}
.navMenu a:hover{
color: #f1f1f1;
}
.container:hover .navMenu {
left: 0;
}
.container:hover .body {
left: 250px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did refactor a bit your code. For the solution no need to use `position: absolute`, just change the **width** in the menu to **0**  and the nav box with will be collapse. And for a trigger simple **javascript**.

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-button');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

const openMenu = () => {
  body.classList.toggle('menu-open');
};
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', openMenu);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

nav {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  position: relative;
  gap: 15px;
  padding: 3rem 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #111;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

nav a {
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #818181;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

body.menu-open nav {
  flex: 1 0 200px;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-button {
  width: max-content;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-button:hover .bar1,
body.menu-open .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.menu-button:hover .bar2,
body.menu-open .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.menu-button:hover .bar3,
body.menu-open .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">about</a>
  <a href="#">services</a>
  <a href="#">clients</a>
  <a href="#">contacts</a>
</nav>
<main>
  <header>
    <div class="menu-button">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <h1>Cal's Blog</h1>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur ea, fugiat nostrum quod voluptates quo quibusdam rerum dolorem rem, odio cumque veritatis qui? Maxime delectus natus dignissimos est, voluptates dolores? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur
    adipisicing elit. Facere repudiandae ipsum id illo recusandae officia assumenda voluptatem inventore dolor vero ipsa corporis, velit at architecto incidunt, ad eos nobis voluptatibus?
  </p>
</main>
```

Comment: i played around with your code a bit and found that if  i delete the:

Comment: I did update `css` options. Now, the navigation is collapses with `flex: 1 0 0%;` I think this is a cleaner approach. And what do you want to ask me about *delete*